# How can i read SMS data from long sms programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I done read incoming sms data using broadcast receiver. But in this case my incoming sms data would be larger (more then 150 character ).Sms received two separate part,in this time broadcast receiver read sms data. But i cant get full content in same variable.
Please give me the solution. Thanks in advance.

> This is my incoming sms
>
> TrackLocationResponse@80.233555,13.050061666666666!80.233555,13.050061666666666!80.233555,13.050061666666666!80.233555,13.050061666666666!80.23430333333334,13.052583333333333!80.23430333333334,13.052583333333333!80.23430333333334,13.052583333333333!

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        if (b == null) {
                return;
            }
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) b.get("pdus");
            if (pdus != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                    body = SMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    number = SMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    Log.d("Sms Recived", body + " : " + number);//this line working properly

                }
    if ((body.startsWith("TrackLocationResponse"))) {
                    String recvedContent[]=body.split("@");
                    Log.d("getSmsLocationTracking", recvedContent[1]);
                    //this not working only when sms content is large   
                }
}
```

Comment: The answer on the linked duplicate shows how to concatenate the whole message. Even though that question talks about a non-English language, the answer is the same for yours. The issue in both cases is multipart messages.

Comment: I see that answer, i found out only one word different from my question that's  =>  "long smsReceiveTime = msg.getTimestampMillis();"  but its not correct solution know. But i want to get full sms content intensely

Comment: Yeah, yours was close. You just need to concatenate the message bodies in the loop.

Comment: Thanks dude.! I got that point.. actually "StringBulder.append" is the solution.. :-)

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, I didn't notice you'd edited your comment. I thought you meant that you saw the `StringBuilder`. Anyhoo, sounds like you've got it now. Cheers!

Comment: Cheers..! Anyway Thanks a lot... :-)